# How to write a script form select with boostrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when creating a form with boostrap. especially on select. Please help:(

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="jenis_pendidikan" class="col-md-2 control-label">Jenis Pendidikan</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="jenis_pendidikan" class="form-control" name="jenis_pendidikan">
            <option>SD</option>
            <option>SMP</option>
            <option>SMA/SMK</option>
            <option>Perguruan Tinggi</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Source]

Result:

[image: Display]

Comment: I've tried your code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r7dx97rm/ and everything looks good.

Comment: I can see it working here https://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/jn06j1p1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"             href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100|Luckiest+Guy|Quicksand:300|Asap:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Roboto|Signika:700" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group">
                       

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="jenis_pendidikan">Jenis Pendidikan</label>
                                <select  id="jenis_pendidikan" class="form-control" name="jenis_pendidikan">
                                    <option>SD</option>
                                    <option>SMP</option>
                                    <option>SMA/SMK</option>
                                    <option>Perguruan Tinggi</option>
                                </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Have a look at the above snippet it is work.

You need to put the `label` just above your `select`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. very helpful:)